# Jquery click handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grid, click, jquery-ui-sortable

I have made a photogallery admin script I dont know how andle click event.
Is more sample see to explayn

[open](http://jsfiddle.net/Jju53/5/)

Any code improvement is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Bind a handler to the click event of the buttons. You can use `parent()` to get the div holding the image.

```
$('.photo_tools .rotate_l').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
    ...
});
```